# Is a unicode escape valid in the let keyword

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer

Is using a unicode escape sequence valid in the `let` keyword?

Restating: Is the following code valid?

```
l\u0065t a = 1;
```

Is it equivalent to this code:

```
let a = 1;
```

Comment: Why don't you try it ?

Comment: @PedroLobito It's a language-lawyer question. Implementations could be wrong.

Comment: The standard seems somewhat ambiguous in this area. `let` is not in the  reserved word grammar. V8 in google chrome says it's invalid.

Comment: If you try this in Firefox, you get `SyntaxError: keywords must be written literally, without embedded escapes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.

ECMAScript does allow Unicode escape sequences in string literals, template literals and regex literals (so far so expected), and [even in identifier names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/1048572) ([more details](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6)). It does however not allow them in [raw source text](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-source-text)<sup>1</sup>, so they cannot form things such as keywords, other tokens and whitespaces.

(This has not changed since ES5. You also were not allowed, and continue to be not allowed, to use escape sequences in `var`.)

<sub>1: One could of course imagine an implementation that interprets anything, including escape characters, to derive a source text<sup>2</sup>, but that would be a) weird and b) outside the scope of ECMAScript. Think of passing a string through `JSON.parse` and `eval` - such a string might as well contain `l\u0065t`.

2: An actual example of something like this (where it actually makes sense) are HTML entities in a `<script>` tag.</sub>

Comment: I would change your example to something that's not a reserved word in ES5. The standard specifically states that escape sequences are not allowed in reserved words.

Comment: @programmerjake: It does? I missed that, can you point me to it?

Comment: see the note in 11.6.2 http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words

Comment: @programmerjake: Oh, right, I looked at [ES5 which doesn't contain that note](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1). Imo it's implicit that *all* tokens must be literal sequences of the respective source characters.

Comment: @programmerjake: That raises the point though whether `var v\u0061r` would be valid though, if `v\u0061r` is strictly not a reserved word that is forbidden in identifiers :-) I guess they actually meant that reserved words are not allowed in the *string values* of identifiers.

Comment: from what I understand `var v\u0061r;` is valid. They don't check the string value of identifiers.

Comment: I don't think so (you certainly can't have a variable named `var`, regardless how you expressed the name). Maybe we should discuss this in another question or right at https://bugs.ecmascript.org/ :-)